# How do I change the input language for Emoji keyboard in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, input-languages, windows-10-1809, emoji-keyboard

My system language is English, but I have set Czechia as a Language for non-Unicode programs and Region formats because some applications didn't work for me - didn't show the special characters correctly. I also use a Czech keyboard layout.

When I activate the Emoji keyboard pressing "Windows + ." it says "Keep typing to find an emoji" in English but when I type there fxp "cry" it won't find anything. I have to type there in Czech language. Is there any way to change this behavior?

I'm running Windows 10 Pro N / 1809 with latest updates.

Comment: @Ramhound I understand that it makes sense but I prefer to use English over Czech language and I'd like to change this. And it's not Keyboard layout related, because on my second PC I have the exact same settings - English display language and Czech keyboard and the Emoji keyboard typing language is English.

Comment: The second pc is running Windows 10 Home. Version should be the same with latest updates .

Comment: I do. I'm watching Netflix on MS Edge and it's not working without Media pack installed. So when any bigger update removes it for me I have to reinstall it manually. How's Media pack related to the Emoji keyboard?

Comment: It might not actually be related.  I am asking questions and more information that might be relevant, so your question has a chance of being answered.  *I won’t be able to help you at this point.*. I hope you figure it out.  All possible relevant information should be in the question body.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*A picture is worth a thousand words:*

[image: Emoji example]

Above examples snipped from [emoji picker](https://www.howtogeek.com/351344/) started using <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> i.e. [Windows logo key   + . (period) during text entry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-keyboard-tips-and-tricks-588e0b72-0fff-6d3f-aeee-6e5116097942)…

Tested using the following language settings:

```
D:\PShell\_test_Get-Culture.ps1
```

> ```
> Language     LangTag KbdID    KbdLayout                  
> --------     ------- -----    ---------                  
> English      en-GB   00000405 Czech                      
> English      en-GB   00000452 United Kingdom Extended    
> Czech        cs      00000405 Czech                      
> Czech        cs      00020409 United States-International
> ```

The `_test_Get-Culture.ps1` script:

```
### _test_Get-Culture.ps1 ###
$gcRegKey = 'HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts'
$gcWULL = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$cgWULLHuman = $gcWULL | ForEach-Object {
    $gcU=$_
    $gcUIMT=$gcU.InputMethodTips
    if ( $gcUIMT ) {
        $gcUIMT | ForEach-Object {
            $cLx=$_.Substring(5)
            $cLz=Get-Item -LiteralPath "$gcRegKey\$cLx"
            $cLy=$cLz.GetValue("Layout Text", $gcU.LanguageTag)
            [psCustomObject]@{
                "Language"  = ($gcU.EnglishName).Replace(' (1453-)','');
                'LangTag'   = $gcU.LanguageTag;
                "KbdID"     = $cLx;
                "KbdLayout" = $cLy
            }
        }
    } else {
            [psCustomObject]@{
                "Language"  = ($gcU.EnglishName).Replace(' (1453-)','');
                'LangTag'   = $gcU.LanguageTag;
                "KbdID"     = '';
                "KbdLayout" = 'N/A'
            }
    }
}
$cgWULLHuman
```

Comment: Thanks for figuring that out! Just one silly question. What's the difference between input language and input keyboard and where do I set it?

Comment: @sczdavos You can use [`Set-WinUserLanguageList`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuserlanguagelist?view=win10-ps) Powershell cmdlet (unfortunately `#requires -RunAsAdministrator`), or _hand-made_ in _Language Preferences_ (`Start` => _Edit language and keyboard options_).  Also read entire thread [What's the difference between a “Keyboard Language” and an “Input Language”?](https://superuser.com/q/438166/376602)

Comment: Thank you I've resolved it. There's an "Override for default input method" settings. Where I had to set the English - Czech instead of Czech - Czech.

Comment: A good picture might be worth a few quid, but I have no idea what I'm looking at.

Comment: @AdamJagosz answer updated 

Comment: I meant I don't know what kind of input you're typing into and most of the time there is no language dropdown wherever I type... 

Comment: @AdamJagosz Black background = text editor; above is _language bar_  (Settings -> Time and language -> Keyboard) _floating on desktop_ (Language bar options). Typed text is _horn_ (English) or _roh_ (Czech). Texts  _smiling face with horns_ or _usmívající se obličej s rohy_  are pop-ups when you point mouse on an emoji… Of course, those are _two_ different use cases linked in one picture…

Comment: Sorry if I'm being stupid but I don't know an app called "text editor", and I have no "Keyboard" option in Windows 10 Settings > Time and language.

Comment: Under common name _"text editor"_: imagine _any_ text input field in _any_ app   (e.g. Notepad, Word, or your browser). I can't believe that you have no _Settings (home)_ -> _Time&Language_ -> _Language_!

Answer (score 3):

I added and English entry (keyboard layout + **language pack**) in Settings > Language > Preferred languages.

I need to switch to that keyboard layout before I can search for emojis in English, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the keyboard corresponding to English language to Chech (in Settings → Time & language)
2. Make sure that your selected input language is English:
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYBFD.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup here where I run my Windows 11 in `English` but also have
`Portuguese Br` language installed in the system. I wanted to search for emojis in `EN` but the searches were always performed in `PTBR` first.

So, after I decided to end this hell, I remembered that this **emoji keyboard is also an app** and I could just use the `Win+Space` shortcut to quickly switch languages and then perform my search in english.