# How to force Windows Emoji Keyboard to search by emoji character name?

Tags: windows-10, unicode, input-languages, emoji-keyboard, emoji

I have multiple languages installed. Emoji search in Windows Emoji Keyboard [is based on current input language](https://superuser.com/a/1451795/20400). How to disable or extend this behavior in order to search by [emoji character name](http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/1.0/emoji-data.txt) regardless the input language (too).