# Windows 10 Emoji Panel text input only searches one language

Tags: windows-10, language, locale, emoji, emoji-keyboard

My current language is English (Israel), and the keyboard is set to English US International.

When I launch the Emoji Panel and type text (in English) it doesn't filter the emojis. It'll only do so if I switch language (to Hebrew), and search the emoji names as they're called in Hebrew.

Is there a way to fix that? When I'm using my English keyboard, I want the emoji panel to search emojis as they're called in English, not Hebrew.

Here's a summary of my settings:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

The problem is that every language you're adding appears in the language bar. You cannot choose to add a language only for display or locale, I don't need 2 Englishes in my keyboard.

Posted issue [here](https://aka.ms/AAabu4v) on **Feedback hub**, please vote.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the input language for Emoji keyboard in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1451149/how-do-i-change-the-input-language-for-emoji-keyboard-in-windows-10)

Comment: @JosefZ it's a related question but slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution which works for me:

- I set Windows display language and all other settings to English United States
- Regional format to Hebrew
- Preferred Languages:

  - English (United States) > Options > Keyboards > United States International
  - Hebrew
- Regional format: Hebrew (that's a compromise, but I can live with it)

This is what my settings look like:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]